# Thread-safe function call: std::mutex inside a std::shared_ptr

Tags: multithreading, c++11, design-patterns, mutex, shared-ptr

I have an application that makes a number of calls to an external library. One of these calls is not thread-safe so everything will crash if I don't guard it somehow.

I tried to use the following pattern, i.e. wrapping a `mutex` inside a `shared_ptr`. Note that this class may be instantiated at many different places in the application from different threads.

```
class MyClass 
{
public:
    MyClass(const std::shared_ptr<std::mutex>& mutex) :
        _mutex(mutex)
    {
    }

    MyClass(MyClass&& other) :
        _mutex(other._mutex)
    {
    }

    void run()
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(*_mutex);

        ExtLib::runNonThreadSafeFunction();
    }
private:
    std::shared_ptr<std::mutex> _mutex;
};
```

Are there any risks using this approach? I'm suspecting that it causes `dead-locks` but I'm not sure.

If this is not a good approach, how would you implement it?

**Note:** I am also considering using a `static mutex` inside the `run-function`, but I believe `Visual Studio 2013` doesn't support it: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/808030/runtime-crash-with-static-std-mutex).

Comment: Is the `runNonThreadSafeFunction` function call all you protect with this mutex? Then it could be a `static` variable, either locally inside the `run` function or class member. No need for any shared pointer.

Comment: This looks correct. Just be sure the mutex is global. It shouldn't cause any deadlock. Assuming a thread will not get in the library forever and there is no callback to the calling component.

Comment: `const std::shared_ptr<std::mutex>& mutex` should be `std::shared_ptr<std::mutex> mutex` and you should `std::move` it into the local storage.  `MyClass(MyClass&& other)` is wrong, you are copying not moving, it should be `MyClass(MyClass const& other)`.  I wouldn't implement `MyClass(MyClass&& other)`.  In MSVC2015 `MyClass(MyClass const& other)=default` is correct.  Most importantly, where do you get the `shared_ptr` from?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I like the idea of making the mutex static, but I'm worried about the vs2013 crash that I linked to in the post.

Comment: @Yakk Actually, I stripped away all irrelevant things from my class when I posted the code - the move constructor would make more sense if you saw the original class. :) Why is it better to pass the shared_ptr by copy instead of reference?

Comment: @rodolk I always pass the same shared_ptr to each instance of MyClass. I guess that is what you mean with global (?)

Comment: @4-bit Yours possibly mandates a needless add/remove ref.  In general, if you are storing a copy of a cheap to move object, pass by value not `const&`.